# Scaling Kafka: how new event processing capacity is added dynamically?

Tags: apache-kafka

To a large extent getting throughout in a system on Kafka rests of these degrees of freedom:

- (highly recommended) messages should be share nothing. If share-nothing they can be randomly assigned to different partitions within a topic and processed independently of other messages
- (highly recommended) the partition count per topic should be sized. More partitions per topic equals greater possible levels of parallelism
- (highly recommended) to avoid hotspots within a topic partition, the Kafka key may need to include time or some other varying data point so that a single partition does not unintentionally get the majority of the work
- (helpful) the processing time per message should be small when possible
- https://dzone.com/articles/20-best-practices-for-working-with-apache-kafka-at mentions other items fine tuning these principles

Now suppose that on an otherwise OK system, one will get a lot of new work. For example, a new and large client may be added mid-day or an existing client may need to onboard a new account adding zillions of new events. How do we scale horizontally adding new capacity for this work?

If the messages are truly share-nothing **throughout the entire system** --- I have a data pipeline of services where A gets a message, processes it, publishes a new message to another service B, and so on --- adding new capacity to the system could be easy as sending a message on an separate administration topic telling the consumer task(s) to spin up new threads. Then so long as the number of partitions in the topic(s) is not a bottleneck, one would have indeed add new processing capacity.

This approach is certainly doable but is still un-optimal in these respects:

- Work on different clientIds is definitely share-nothing. Merely adding new threads takes work faster, but any new work would interleave behind and within the existing client work. Had a new topic been available with a new pub/sub process pair(s), the new work could be done in parallel if the cluster has spare capacity on the new topic(s)
- In general, share-nothing work may not be always possible at every step in a data pipeline. If ordering was ever required, the addition of new subscriber threads could get messages out of order for a given topic, partition. This happens when there are M paritions in a topic but >M subscriber threads. I have one such order sensitive case. It's worth noting then that ordering effectively means at most 1 subscriber thread per partition so sizing paritions may be even more important.
- Tasks may not be allowed to add topics at runtime by the sysadmin
- Even if adding topics at runtime is possible, system orchestration is required to tell various produces that clientID no longer is associated with the old topic T, but rather T'. WIP on T should be flushed first before using T'

How does the Cassandra community deal with adding capacity at runtime or is this day-dreaming? Adding new capacity via in this way seems to roughly center on:

Dynamic, elastic horizontal capacity seems to broadly center on these principles:

- have spare capacity on your cluster
- have extra unused topics for greater parallelism; create them at runtime or pre-create but not use if sys-admins don't allow dynamically creation
- equip the system so that events for a given clientID can be intercepted before they enter the pipeline and deferred to a special queue, know when existing events on the clientID have flushed through the system, then update config(s) sending the held/deferred events and any new events on new clients to the new topic
- Telling consumers to spin up more listeners
- Dynamically adding more partitions? (Doubt that's possible or practical)

Comment: "new subscriber threads could get messages out of order for a given topic, partition [...] when there are M partions in a topic but >M subscriber threads" it was my understanding that a) the partition size is the maximum size of parallelism, ie number of consumers within a group and b) order is guaranteed within a topic for a given key. Do you have several members (ie "threads" ) in a group?

Comment: For a topic with N partitions it's possible to run >N listener threads. So for a partition n in N there's at least two threads taking events hence order lost

Comment: For a topic with N partitions, only N members of a given consumer groups will receive messages. I don't know why you're talking about threads; the Kafka parallelization unit is partitions, seems to me like you can easily single-thread a given consumer.